# Как отключить показ label и подсказок в chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Есть готовая библиотека графиков `chart.js`, как можно убрать `label` и подсказки при наведении на точки и сетку с заднего фона?

Сниппет: [ссылка](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zajqqM)

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'line',

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: ["2015-10-01", "2015-10-01", "2015-10-01", "2015-10-01", "2015-10-01", "2015-10-01", "2015-10-01"],
    datasets: [{
      label: {
        display: false,
      },
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: [0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400],
    }]
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: посмотри как тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632529/chart-js-how-to-hide-title-of-tooltip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы скрыть заголовок всплывающей подсказки, нужно вернуть пустую функцию

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: false,
      callbacks: {
        title: function() {},
        label: function() {}
      }
    }
  },
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: "line",
  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: [
      "2015-10-01",
      "2015-10-01",
      "2015-10-01",
      "2015-10-01",
      "2015-10-01",
      "2015-10-01",
      "2015-10-01"
    ],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
      borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
      data: [0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400]
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: А как убрать клетки с фона и как убрать вот этот блок сверху? 
http://prntscr.com/jxswc3

Comment: legend:{display: false}

Comment: поправил options, проверяй